# rails 3 dumping PostgreSQL database into schema.rb ignores primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Changes:

```
create_table "accounts", :force => true do |t|
  ...some columns...
end
```

Into:

```
create_table "accounts", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "id",            :null => false
  ...some other columns...
end
```

I've done research on this, noticing a fix placed in a gem we're not using for a similar issue, https://github.com/tchandy/octopus/commit/8d977981d2700e80a2c171d0b116c4d37309894c. The only applicable gem we have in our Gemfile is the pg gem.

**[EDIT]**

Using Rails 3.1.3 and pg 0.11.0

Using postgresql 9.0.6

```
Table "public.accounts"
 Column  |     Type   |                    Modifiers                       
---------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id      | integer    | not null default nextval('accounts_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Let me know if I need to include a link to a simple Rails project demonstrating the issue (I don't have this project made, yet). Also, if no one has an answer, I can start diving into Rails internals for the dump code, but I was trying to avoid that. If this is indeed fixed in the newest version of Rails (3.2, confirmed with a github commit), then I'll upgrade, instead.

Comment: Which version of Rails and pg gem are you using. I am using Rails 3.2.2 and pg 0.13.2 and I am not seeing the `:id => false` nor subsequent addition of explicit `t.integer "id"...` I wonder if this has anything to do with accounts being an otherwise empty table.  Why is that?  What does the initial migration look like?

Comment: edited my question with the schema and version information. @tharrison, when you do a db:schema:dump, it doesn't run your migrations so the migration file doesn't have anything to do with this, AFAIK.

Comment: Well, no there's no direct linkage between migrations and schema, except that the normal way to create or modify your schema in the course of developing a rails app is to create migrations; I assumed you had.  So, in my case, I was unable to reproduce the problem you report.  A difference is that your create table block is empty -- no explicitly created columns.  What is the reason for this?  Perhaps you could add a column to test and see if you get the same result.

Comment: It's not actually, just saw no point in revealing all the columns. editing my response to reflect this...